# Nextpeer : Waiting for players screen getting blank in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, nextpeer

I have recently integrated nextpeer to my iPhone game. What I observed is while I am launching NextPeer dashboard after clicking on "Play" button there should be waiting for other players screen which is getting blank, no players other players is being loaded. Any Idea guys, what should be the issue ?

Help would highly appreciated.

Thanks
Kuldeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm a developer for Nextpeer.)

This issue has to do with resource bundle mismatch. Note that 5 different resource bundles come with the framework, you should choose the one that matches your game (for example, if your game runs on iPhone and iPad in landscape mode, choose NPResources_iPad_iPhone_Landscape.bundle.

You can also contact us directly at support@nextpeer.com.

Cheers!

Comment: @vlamidir Apart from that, I am facing one another issue where I am not able to get the results screen after tournament completes. Please advice on that

Comment: @Kuldeep, make sure you're calling +[Nextpeer reportControlledTournamentOverWithScore:] and not +[Nextpeer reportForfeitForCurrentTournament]. And don't hesitate to contact our support :)

Comment: Sure Vladmimir I will contact support if needed.

Comment: How would I get the result screen when the Tournament is not in GameControlled!

Comment: The result screen will come automatically when the tournament ends (when the set tournament time passes). Just make sure not to call reportForfeitForCurrentTournament.

Comment: Hey Vladimir Gritsenko how to create other player ghost image in our game in multiplayer tournament through NextPeer?

Comment: @Kuldeep, very short answer: use our P2P features, especially -[Nextpeer unreliablePushDataToOtherPlayers:], to broadcast position data to the other players. We're working on a tutorial for ghosts right now. If you're stuck, drop me a line at vladimir@nextpeer.com.